# Create nested doctine objects with one GraphQl query with API Platform

Tags: symfony, graphql, doctrine, apollo-client, api-platform.com

I have a basic Entity in my symfony application:

```
/**
* @ApiResource()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CardRepository::class)
*/
class Card
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=CardReference::class, mappedBy="card", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
    private $cardReferences;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
   private $name;
```

As you can see - there is another Entity: `CardReference` with a OneToMany Relationship.

So now - when I create a new `Card`:

```
mutation AddCard($name: String!) {
    createCard(input: { name: $name }) {
        card {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder what way to go for creating also a `CardReference`. 
Because this comes everytime hand in hand. Every `Card` needs at least one `CardReference` - so a default one should be created on creation of the card.

Ist the right way to do it with another GraphQL query afterwards? 
Or is this an usecase for writing a [custom resolver](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#workflow-of-the-resolvers)?

Answer (score 0):

API Platform used to allow nested subresource creation in early days, the case is subjected to RFC specification standardization.

See issue [#3258](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3258) For more information.
Right now you can create `cardRefrence` separately and provide it's IRI to your  `Card` resource to get around with standard resource access pattern.

```
mutation AddCard($name: String!) {
    createCard(input: { 
        name: $name 
        cardReferences: [
            '/card_references/1',
            '/card_references/2'
            #... other IRI etc.
        ]
        }) {
        card {
            name
            #... Access CardReference Relay here which will return related IRI
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You could use custom mutation to achieve this, but in my opinion & experience making api platform to go out of spec & standard always creates other set of problems, which you have to deal with. Try to create schema in such a way that it allows you be flexible enough to separate Data Models with underlying DB schema, you usually end up writing your own persisters, dto, data providers & resolver for types you define.

> Take this note as grain of salt as there are usecases where
>   api-platform gives ease of use to setup api quickly and the problem I
>   got might not be relevant here.